# input property does not change if i use mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs

I new on Reactjs. I have Angular background.
I am faced with the problem of change manually field latitude.
I try to use  onChange with handleChange- but it does not work
What am I doing wrong?

Code

```
   class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    handleChange(value) {
        let coords= {...this.state.coords}
        coords.latitude = value;
        this.setState({coords})

    }


    render() {
        return (<div>
                    <label htmlFor ="latitude">Широта</label>
                    <input id='latitude' type='text'
                           onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event.target.value)} value={this.props.coords.latitude} />
                    <label htmlFor ="longitude">Долгота</label>
                    <input id='longitude'  onChange={(type) => {
                               this.setState({type});
                    }}  type='text' value={this.props.coords.longitude}  />
                    <input onClick={this.handleClick} type='submit' value='Посмотреть на карте'/>
                </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        coords: state.coords
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Form);
```

Comment: Do you want to use `props` or `state`? I am only asking because you seem to read everything from your props, but then use `setState` in attempt to update something...

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing props given by the `mapStateToProps` connector with the internal `state` of your component.

If what you want is to change the latitude in the store, you need to `dispatch` an event that make that change and then the component will automatically change it's value.

You need to implement `mapDispatchToProps` as well.

See the [official guide](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) which mention how to properly implement this.